# The "all apps" button disappeared from my Dock

Tags: dock

This button disappeared from my Dock. I checked the Dock settings in System Settings and there doesn't appear to be any toggle to enable or disable it. So how do I add it back?

I don't actually know what it's called so it's difficult to search for and every search query I could come up with was irrelevant.

[image]

Comment: what did it do when working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Launchpad.

[image]

Find it in your Applications folder and drag it back into the Dock.
You can do this for any app, to keep it permanently in the Dock. To remove you just drag it back out again until it says Remove, then let go.